# Issue getting child to fill vertically within a Flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a child div with a table inside it. I want this div to fill out vertically within the parent container.

I have tried different methods, positions, flex, margins, etc., but I cannot get it to stretch out vertically within the parent container.

Essentially I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="GridViewContainer wrapper">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want **GridViewContainer wrapper** to fill out the rest of **content**

[image]

I have set up a demo here: ( I set the table div to a fixed height of 400px for demo purposes)

**DEMO -** https://jsfiddle.net/7ashn3b5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `display:flex` on the parent container.

Since you haven't made `.content` a flex container, `flex-direction:column` is being ignored, and flex items are ignoring flex properties.

Once you add `display:flex` to `.content` (and remove the `height:400px`), you can apply `flex:1` to `.GridViewContainer wrapper`, which tells it to stretch the full available height of its parent.

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7ashn3b5/5/)

Comment: Hi Micheal I got it all working in the end. Thanks for the support.